# Google map center map bound by two positions with some padding

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Am trying to center a map camera position and bound it based on two positions with route ploylines. So in my code i have

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
    builder.include(site_marker.getPosition());
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, (int)DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

The above loads the map with two position and produces the following

[image]

As from the screenshot i would like to push the two locations such that the green current position is at the bottom and the site_marker is at the top, that is top to bottom view of the route by rotating the map. Also i would like to move the positions away from the map edges such that there is some padding between screen edge and the marker positions

That is the final route i want it to look like

[image]

As you can see from the last image the two positions aren't at the screen edges they are a bit away from the edge

What else do I need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try changing the DEFAULT ZOOM value, the second parameter is padding, try 50.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#public-static-cameraupdate-newlatlngbounds-latlngbounds-bounds,-int-padding